# Load a view & controller after AUTH_REQUIRED error and route resolve has been rejected

Tags: angularjs, authentication, firebase, firebase-authentication

In AngularJS (I'm a newbie) how could I 'resolve' a promise that has been rejected during routing?

My app requires all visitors to be authenticated either anonymously or by specifying their credentials -- I'm using Firebase and AngularFire.

Initially, when a visitor navigates to a `route` I check if they are authenticated with a `resolve` during routing using the `$routeProvider`.

If the visitor is not authenticated (the `error === 'AUTH_REQUIRED'`) the promise is rejected. I then authenticate the user anonymously.

As the promise was rejected, the route's `controller` and `view` did not load.

**Q: How can I load the route's `controller` and `view` after I have anonymously authenticated the visitor?**

I imagine I could just somehow refresh/reload the route, but I would also imagine there is a better way.

So for an unauthenticated user who navigates to a route that requires authentication (almost all will):

1. Authentication is required; reject the promise
2. Authenticate the visitor anonymously
3. Anonymous authentication is successful; load the route's `controller` and `view` (and anything else) as would have happened, had the visitor already been authenticated

As I understand, I cannot resolve an already rejected promise.

I hope you can help; here is an example of what I am currently doing to try and achieve this:

```
var app = angular.module('vo2App', ['firebase', 'ngRoute']);

app.config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider
  .when('/', {
    controller: 'HomeCtrl',
    resolve: {
      'currentAuth': ['Auth', function (Auth) {
        return Auth.$requireAuth();
      }]
    },
    templateUrl: './views/home.html'
  })
}]);

app.run(['$rootScope', 'Auth', function ($rootScope, Auth) {
  $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeError', function (event, next, prev, error) {
    if (error === 'AUTH_REQUIRED') {
      console.log('Unauthorized');

      Auth.$authAnonymously().then(function (authData) {
        console.log(authData);
      }).catch(function(error) {
        console.log(error);
      });
    }
  });
}]);

app.controller('HomeCtrl', ['currentAuth', function (currentAuth) {
  console.log(currentAuth);
}]);

app.factory('Auth', ['$firebaseAuth', function ($firebaseAuth) {
  var ref = new Firebase('https://myvo2-mx.firebaseio.com');

  return $firebaseAuth(ref);
}]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why doesn't `Auth.$requireAuth();` call `Auth.$authAnonymously()` so that you can reject the promise only if both failed.

Basically,

```
var defer = $q.defer();
Auth.$requireAuth().then(defer.resolve,function(){
   Auth.$authAnonymously().then(defer.resolve,defer.reject)
})
return defer.promise;
```

Comment: Ah, i get it. Thank you! What if `Auth.$authAnonymously()` fails? I currently `catch` this (abiet I only log the error). Also, as I would be using this in most of my routes, is there a way I could reuse this without including it in every 'resolve' for each route?

Comment: Remember that the second argument you pass to a `then` is a function which calls when a promise is rejected. You can do your logging and then reject it. Also since, you have put your resolve in the parent route `\`, the resolve will be inherited in all your routes, so you might not need to place it in every route.

Comment: i get you; I could `defer.reject` with a function that deals with this, and then finally rejects the promise?

I have just tried to add a second route but it unfortunately did not inherit the `resolve` from the `/` route. I think this only works with `ui-router`. I have found this however which might help me (the second answer): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20963709/routeprovider-injecting-same-dependency-for-all-routes

Comment: I have tried to implement this, and thought I had got there, but it seems when a visitor lands on the website for the first time, the promise is always rejected -- like it isn't waiting for the `$authAnonymousl` to get it's async response. Any ideas why that might be?

Comment: I will have to see some code to suggest anything. Can you share snippet of how you have wired both promises?